# GridGain Cache Template Xml Usage

Tags: templates, config, gridgain

I am wondering if I can configure a cache via xml configuration, but to avoid repeating similar elements use the cache template?

I've not been able to find an example of this, the documentation shows this as the template definition ~

```
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="cacheConfiguration">
        <list>
            <bean abstract="true" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration" id="cache-template-bean">
                <!-- when you create a template via XML configuration, you must add an asterisk to the name of the template -->
                <property name="name" value="myCacheTemplate*"/>
                <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
                <property name="backups" value="2"/>
                <!-- Other cache parameters -->
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

say I have caches named cacheA and cacheB, how would the xml look if I wanted them to use this template, would it be something like this ~

```
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="cacheConfiguration">
        <list>
            <bean abstract="true" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration" id="cache-template-bean">
                <!-- when you create a template via XML configuration, you must add an asterisk to the name of the template -->
                <property name="name" value="myCacheTemplate*"/>
                <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
                <property name="backups" value="2"/>
                <!-- Other cache parameters -->
            </bean>
        <!--  ---------------------------------------------------- -->
        <!--  How do I get these caches to use the template above? -->
        <!--  ---------------------------------------------------- -->
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                <!-- when you create a template via XML configuration, you must add an asterisk to the name of the template -->
                <property name="name" value="cacheA"/>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                <!-- when you create a template via XML configuration, you must add an asterisk to the name of the template -->
                <property name="name" value="cacheB"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Possibly this is not how its meant to be used, I'm not sure from the documentation, if anyone has any thoughts please let me know.

Thanks,
LS

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 ways to build that configuration:

a) in XML using parent template:

```
<bean name="ignite.cfg" parent="default.cfg">
        <property name="cacheConfiguration">
            <list>
                <bean parent="cache-template">
                    <property name="name" value="replicated_tx"/>
                    <property name="cacheMode" value="REPLICATED"/>
                    <property name="atomicityMode" value="TRANSACTIONAL"/>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="cache-template" abstract="true" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
        <property name="rebalanceMode" value="SYNC"/>
        <property name="writeSynchronizationMode" value="FULL_SYNC"/>
    </bean>
```

b) Using cache template in code:

```
<bean name="ignite.cfg" parent="default.cfg">
        <property name="cacheConfiguration">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">                        
                    <property name="name" value="myCacheTemplate*"/>
                    <property name="cacheMode" value="REPLICATED"/>
                    <property name="atomicityMode" value="TRANSACTIONAL"/>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

And create it using the same name:

```
IgniteCache<Object, Object> cache = start.getOrCreateCache("myCacheTemplateXX");
```